# How to increase the number of plotted cycles

Tags: matlab

I've plotted a sin wave that takes one second to complete an oscillation and has an amplitude of one.

```
F = 1 ;
A = 1 ;
x = linspace (0,1,100) ;
y = A * sin(2 * pi * F * x) ;
plot(x, y, 'b.-'),xlim([0 3.5]),ylim([-1 1]);
```

The problem is, only one oscillation is plotted on the graph. How can I get more cycles or oscillations to be plotted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `linspace` output was defined between `0` and `1`. If you want to fill the whole plot, whose `x` upper limit is `3.5`, change the code as follows:

```
F = 1;
A = 1;
x = linspace (0,3.5,100); % from 0 to 3.5, not from 0 to 1
y = A * sin(2 * pi * F * x);
plot(x, y, 'b.-'),xlim([0 3.5]),ylim([-1 1]);
```

If you want to have more control over this, just define a variable which represent your `x-axis` upper limit so you don't have to change too many things when you want to modify the plot:

```
F = 1;
A = 1;
x_hi = 3.5;
x = linspace (0,x_hi,100);
y = A * sin(2 * pi * F * x);

plot(x, y, 'b.-');
xlim([0 x_hi]);
ylim([-1 1]);
```

Comment: Clear-cut explanation!